# is this a theorem of ZF?

Tags: set-theory

Is the following a theorem of ZF?

> For any set $x$: the rank of $x$ is the order type of the natural order on the set of all rankes of elements of $TC(x)$.

Where $TC(x)$ is the transitive closure of $x$, defined in the [usual manner](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Transitive_Closure_(Set_Theory)).

Comment: The obvious proof by induction on rank works fine and doesn't need choice as far as I can tell; what's the issue? (Of course we need the right definition of "rank:" it's crucially $rk(x)=\min\{\alpha: x\in V_{\alpha+1}\}$.)

Comment: I was just worried that it might need choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fun little exercise to confirm your suspicion:

> The following are equivalent for any set $x$:
>
> 1. $\operatorname{rank}(x)=\alpha$,
> 2. $\alpha=\min\{\beta\mid\operatorname{tcl}(x)\cap V_{\beta+1}\setminus V_\beta=\varnothing\}$.

In other words, the rank of a set is the smallest ordinal that is not the rank of an element of $\operatorname{tcl}(x)$. I never found this claim in any of the standard textbooks (which is admittedly kind of odd), so you can find it embedded in the proof of Proposition 2.2 of my paper with David Asperó,

> David Asperó and Asaf Karagila, **Dependent Choice, Properness, and Generic Absoluteness.** *Review of Symbolic Logic* (to appear). [Journal](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1755020320000143), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.04077).